# My game has a problem where it draws moves after 3 cliks

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game in pygame but I have a problem where it will only draw the moves after 3 cliks. here's the code:

```py
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                input_x = 155+((x-50)//200)*195
                input_y = 155+((y-50)//200)*195
                if Turn == 1:
                    circle_cord_x.append(input_x)
                    circle_cord_y.append(input_y)
                    Turn = 0
                elif Turn == 0:
                    X_cord_x.append(input_x)
                    X_cord_y.append(input_y)
                    Turn = 1
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        screen.fill((185, 105, 13))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0),
                        [50, 50, 400, 400], 10)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0),
                        [250, 50, 400, 400], 10)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0),
                        [50, 250, 400, 400], 10)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0),
                        [250, 250, 400, 400], 10)
        n = 0
        while n < len(circle_cord_x) - 1:
            temp_x = circle_cord_x[n]
            temp_y = circle_cord_y[n]
            O(temp_x, temp_y)
            n = n + 1
        n = 0
        while n < len(X_cord_x) - 1:
            temp_x = X_cord_x[n]
            temp_y = X_cord_y[n]
            X(temp_x, temp_y)
            n = n + 1
 
        pygame.display.update()
```

I excluded the functions from the code above.

Comment: You can replace both of your loops with `for x,y in circle_cord_x:` / `O(x,y)` and `for x,y in X_cord_x:` / `X(x,y)`.  The way you have written them, you will always skip the final point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the loops where you loop over all coordinates of the lists. The condition, `while n < len(circle_cord_x) - 1`, makes the loop end when `n` reaches `len(circle_cord_x) - 1`. However, this number is still the last index of the list. By consequence, the last element is skipped. This means that you will only see a cross once you added a new cross to the list and the cross is no longer the last element of the list. Because also a circle is placed, this does happen on the third click.

The easy solution would be to turn the condition into `while n < len(circle_cord_x)` or into `while n <= len(circle_cord_x) - 1`. However, you could better change them into for loops, to prevent any misunderstanding in the future:

```py
for temp_x, temp_y in zip(circle_cord_x, circle_cord_y):
    O(temp_x, temp_y)

for temp_x, temp_y in zip(X_cord_x, X_cord_y):
    X(temp_x, temp_y)
```

In this example, I have used the [`zip` function](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/). It returns an iterator containing tuples with the next element of each list passed in as an argument. Using [tuple unpacking](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/) in our for loop, we assign the elements of the first list, containing the x coordinates, to the variable `temp_x` and the elements of the second list to the `temp_y` variable. This allows us to iterate easily over multiple lists at the same time.